# joining an array causes to join them as objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a callback with a parameter `items` which contains an array:

```
[<article>..</article>,<article>...</article>,<article>..</article>]
```

What I needed to do is join these items so what I did was:

```
items = items.join('');
```

But when I `console.log(items)` I am seeing:

```
[object HTMLElement][object HTMLElement][object HTMLElement][object HTMLElement]
```

How do I merge this array properly?

Comment: What did you expect to happen? a merge fo the articles text? If so, you'll need to create an array of the elements's innerText property. and than do the join as you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have objects, of which they can't be automatically serialised into HTML with `join()`.

If your browser supports `outerHTML`, you could do...

```
var html = $.map(items, function(item) { return item.outerHTML; }).join("");
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Swj3j/).

Otherwise, you could do...

```
var fauxDocFrag = $("<div />");
$.each(items, function(key, item) { fauxDocFrag.append(item); });
var html = fauxDocFrag.html();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KhsG2/).

Comment: but how come when I `console.log` the items before joining them they appear as an array of text?

Comment: @Severus Your browser is trying to be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Here i have done complete bins for above issue. you can go through demo link.

**Demo** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp7n
**HTML**

```
<input type="button" id="btn1" value="Get Object Array Text" />
<input type="button" id="btn2" value="Reset" />
<div id="result">
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    var items = ["<article>Article-1:Text</article>", "<article>Article-2:Text</article>", "<article>Article-3:Text</article>", "<article>Article-4:Text</article>", "<article>Article-5:Text</article>"];

    $("#btn1").click(function() {
        var result = "";
        $.each(items, function(key, item) {
            if ($(item).text().trim() != "") {
                if (key > 0) result += " ";
                result += $(item).text().trim();
            }
        });
        if (result != "") {
            $("#result").html(result);
            $("#result").show('slow');
        }
    });

    //Reset Result
    $("#btn2").click(function() {
        $("#result").html('').css('display', 'none');
    });
});
```

**Demo** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp7n